# How to scale an image based on device size in visual studio storyboard

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uiimageview, storyboard

I am currently using visual studio 2019 and I am trying to display an image based on the device size. For example if the device was an SE the image would be small although if it was an iPad the image would be big. I would I do this?

Comment: You could use Auto Layout . At the heart of Auto Layout is the idea of constraints or rules that define the placement of an element or set of elements in the context of other elements on the screen. Because the elements are not tied to a particular position on the screen, constraints help create an adaptive layout that looks good on different screen sizes and device orientations. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/designer/designer-auto-layout

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I have been using auto layout although it says that I need to input a height and width although I don’t want a set height I want it to be able to change based on the device size

Comment: You could set the distance between the image and  the border of screen (or other control of screen)